# Sharepoint list views are very slow after SP1, depending on user on web application policy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list-view

We installed SP1 this weekend, after all user complain about a site collection which is very slow.

We were able to isolate the problem to permissions which is very weird.

If somebody is farm admin, or its in the web application policy with full control, the website even with big views that returns 2000 items, it takes 5 seconds to load.

Once I remove my self from web application user policy, or farm administrator, then the same pages become very slow to me (50 or 60 seconds).

So, we isolated the problem, no idea about the cause, any idea is welcome.

Comment: how many items you trying to retrive via View? how many column in the view? what is your list view threshold?

Comment: 1500 list items, list view threshold is too high 50,000, but none of the views have that ammount.

Comment: did you try to enable the developer dashboard and see on where /which query sharepoint spending the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem my self, and it was just coincidence after SP1 installation.

The document library has a complex workflow with many states, and after the workflow goes to the last state "completed", the item itself gets broken permissions.

We have 17,000 document sets there with 9000 broken permissions

Per Microsoft recommendations, 5000 should be the limit on unique security scopes.

Solution:
1. Move the completed document sets to another library (archive).
2. Leave the operational ones on the main library.
3. In the archive document library, use only one permission for the entire library, not unique.

I have documented the entire story here: 
http://www.luisevalencia.com/2014/06/18/troubleshooting-slow-sharepoint-2013-list-views/

Answer (score -1):

You can create SharePoint index column. Here is some link to handle large list in SharePoint 2010 i would say you can use the idea for SharePoint 2013
http://www.sharepointboco.com/performance-with-sharepoint-2010-large-lists-list-view-throttling/